# Create variables from tag values

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I am trying to create different variables for the 'costcenter' tag. Each tag key "costcenter" has a respective value of "AB12" for example. I want to create a new variable in kusto to show that for every costcenter with the value of "AB12" I want to have this labeled as "HR Department".

I am unfamiliar with the syntax but need to get the value from costcenter that equals "AB12" and then store that as "Hr Department" so when I create a chart it shows HR department instead of "AB12"

resources
| extend cost = tostring(tags['costcenter'])

Answer (score 0):

you can try using the `case()` function, or a mapping from actual value to desired value:

```
resources
| extend costcenter = tostring(tags['costcenter'])
| extend costcenter = case(costcenter == "AB12", "HR Department", costcenter)
| ...
```

```
let mapping = dynamic({"AB12":"HR Department", "AB23":"something else"});
resources
| extend costcenter = mapping[tostring(tags['costcenter'])]
| ...
```